# android java lang runtimeexception fail to connect to camera service

Tags: android, android-camera, flashlight

I am currently working on Flashlight On/OFF. I am getting this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service` I don't know why this error is occurring. I referred to many solutions but my problem was still not solved. When flashlight is on, the error does not occur but when the flashlight is off then the error occurs.

My Code [Main Code](http://pastie.org/9227625).

My Manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

Comment: Provide logcat response please.

Comment: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service". i used try catch so it's display this line.@SoumilDeshpande

Comment: e.printStackTrace() <--- use this and get logcat response

Comment: check this link "http://pastie.org/9227653" here is my logcat.@SoumilDeshpande

Comment: What is here -->(MainClass.java:53)

Comment: Sounds like it failed to connect to the camera service.

Comment: Does your emulator have a camera?

Comment: link to logcat is not valid

Comment: @Opiatefuchs remove the double quote.

Comment: check this kink "http://pastie.org/9227625"@SoumilDeshpande

Comment: I have tested this app in real device.@dcow

Comment: ok now it works. Is Your cam working usually (with other apps)?

Comment: does camera.unlock() help? Call this after camera.open(), this allows to use the camera for other processes while cam is "at work". Maybe a kind of device issue...

Comment: i try this but it's not work. @Opiatefuchs

Comment: For android 6.0 check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39125998/3806413

Comment: I am facing this issue in google nexus 5.1.1, because this device doesn`t have flash light. Keep validation everywhere inside your code or third party libraries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this...

```
 static Camera camera = null;
```

declare it on top.

```
 try{ 
   if(clickOn == true) {
       clickOn = false;
       camera = Camera.open();
       Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
       parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
       camera.setParameters(parameters);
       camera.startPreview();

       remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.button1, View.GONE);
       remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.button2, View.VISIBLE);
       localAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
   } else {
       clickOn = true;
       camera.stopPreview();
       camera.release();
       camera = null;

       remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.button1, View.VISIBLE);
       remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.button2, View.GONE);
       localAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, remoteViews);
   }    
} catch(Exception e) {
   Log.e("Error", ""+e);
}
```

Comment: Don't forgot to release camera

camera.release();

Comment: Why is camera static?

Comment: While this might answer the question, it would be more useful for future readers if you give an explanation

Comment: static Camera still solves de above error  on SDK 29

Answer (score 100):

I had the same issue that none of the answers here solved, so after solving it I am adding my way of solving it. This applies to new android versions that support setting permissions per app (since Marshmallow, 6.0). The permission for camera could be disabled and should be enabled from the app settings.
Settings -> Apps -> [Your App] -> Permissions

More info about this here: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Many thanks! This had me banging my head on the wall for the better part of the day. Any reason they start turned off by default and is this going to be a concern when the app is in production?

Comment: You're welcome! Since Marshmallow you'll have to explicitly take care of asking for needed permissions in your app (not all permissions, only the ones classified as 'dangerous' and camera permisions is one of them. More info about requesting permissions here: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: But what about versions lower than Android 6 ? I am facing the same problem for a Android 5.1 device.

Answer (score 27):

I also saw this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

while experimenting with a flashlight app.   Turns out that I was a bit sloppy with my permissions and copied them into the body of the application block in the manifest.xml file.   So you REALLY need to obey the syntax as documented in:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Otherwise the app will fail with service connection failure on the Camera.open() call.  It should look like this based on your permissions in the question:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

<application
```

Make sure your permission and feature list is contained only in the manifest section, and not buried in the application section!

Comment: There is a problem with these (last 2) lines when you add them to a manifest. Gradle complains : `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs`

Comment: I just rebuilt with AS3.0 / build tools 26.0.2 - no issues.  Does your project have multiple manifests?  See also:  https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/675

Answer (score 14):

This problem may arise in android 6.0 if you didn't enable camera permission for your app. As from Android 6.0 you can handle the app permission weather you will give or not specific permission for an application.

So, you need to enable permission from `settings->apps->your_app->enable camera permission` if its not already enabled.

Comment: I suppose you have to request the permission at runtime for user to allow it. But yes, the core problem is correct.

Answer (score 11):

**If your os version is 6.0 or later version try this, hope this will help.**

```
public class RequestUserPermission {

private Activity activity;
// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
};

public RequestUserPermission(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public  void verifyStoragePermissions() {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
}


**//CALL FROM YOUR ACTIVITY**
 RequestUserPermission requestUserPermission = new RequestUserPermission(this);
    requestUserPermission.verifyStoragePermissions();
```

Answer (score 5):

if you try to open the camera using a cameraID that does not exist, you will receive that same error (java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to Connect to camera service)

look at your code at this block

```
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.stopPreview();
camera.release();
camera = null;
```

Call `release()` to release the camera for use by other applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in `onPause()` (and re-open() it in `onResume().`

In above code imediately after release you are putting null to camera

Answer (score 3):

You need to `stopPreview()` and `release()` once you came back from camera,
     so that other application can able to access it. Make the "Camera" class as static and refer it as `null` in `onPause()`. This resolves my Issue.

Try it out:

```
 public class CameraPhotoCapture extends Activity{
    static Camera mcamera = null;
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mcamera != null) {
            mcamera.stopPreview();
            mcamera.release();
            mcamera = null;
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "releaseCamera -- done");
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mcamera != null) {

            Camera.open();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "openCamera -- done");
        }
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer I can find to this problem is I was not asking for camera permission to the user, and that's why by default camera permission was not available to my app on Marshmallow devices. I simply added permission check for the camera before starting the camera and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Check the camera permission at runtime, and request the permission if it has not be granted. It works for me.

```
    if (checkPermission()) {
        initCamera();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this line, when you're exiting the app :

```
System.exit(0);
```

I just got a code of an Flashlight app from somewhere. It was using `System.exit(0)` to close the app. I removed it, knowing that this is not a good practice. Then I started to receive these errors. I tried the solution of the accepted answer, but then I started receiving some other errors. So, instead of solving them I just put this `System.exit(0)` line back. And, it started working fine. ***I know this is not a good way, but for a small flashlight app, you can try this quick solution.***

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the Required permission in Mainfest file.
2. Ask the Permission to accept the Camera.

It will work for me

Answer (score 0):

**To solve this error you need to get the camera permission in my scenario i solved by the following methods**
*Add the library in build.gradle to get permission*

```
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
```

*use the below following code, in that activity in which you want to ask permission from user*

```
        Dexter.withContext(MainActivity.this)
            .withPermissions(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            ).withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @Override public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {/* ... */}
                @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {/*
        ... */}
            }).check();

Do not forget to add the camera permission in your manifest.



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score -1):

If all your code is ok, you should check are there any other application using your camera. Then you should close other application that currently using your camera.

Answer (score -1):

In my android peoject has the same issue. This is my Logcat error

---

> 03-29 19:26:04.194 224-608/? V/EmulatedCamera_BaseCamera:
>   getCameraInfo 03-29 19:26:04.196 224-224/? I/CameraService:
>   CameraService::connect call (PID -1 "com.proitzen.staffapp", camera ID
>   1) for HAL version default and Camera API version 1 03-29 19:26:04.196
>   224-224/? W/ServiceManager: Permission failure:
>   android.permission.CAMERA from uid=10067 pid=1776 03-29 19:26:04.196
>   224-224/? E/CameraService: Permission Denial: can't use the camera
>   pid=1776, uid=10067 03-29 19:26:04.196 1776-1776/com.proitzen.staffapp
>   W/CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 1: Service
>   not available 03-29 19:26:04.200 1776-1776/com.proitzen.staffapp
>   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

---

No any above solutions worked for me. My android app worked in physical android devices and gave the above error only in Genymotion.

Solution :   start your Genumotion emulator
             Settings --> Apps ---> choose your App --> Permissions --> enable camera and Mic and storage.