# Android unable to switch camera from front to rear

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder

i am using custom camera application.I am using mediarecorder for custom view.and i am using 2 camera says **front camera** & **rear camera**.When i am using it singly like only front camera or only rear camera .,that is working fine.,but i am using one button for fliping front camera to rear camera or  viceversa.i am getting following error.

```
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service**
```

i goggled so many links.saw the solutions but they are not helpful for me..here is my code

```
btn_toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flipcamera();;
            Log.i("clk", "sucess");

        }
    });
```

**here is flipcamera method.**

```
  private void  flipcamera() {
    if(currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
        currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
    }
    else {
        try {
        currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        gebackCameraInstance();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("mmmmmmmmmmm"+e.toString());
    }
    }}


private Camera gebackCameraInstance() {
    try {
        myCamera = Camera.open();
        myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myCamera;
}
private Camera getCameraInstance(){
    //  Camera c = null;
    Log.d("No of cameras",Camera.getNumberOfCameras()+"");
    for (currentCameraId = 0; currentCameraId < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); currentCameraId++) {
        CameraInfo camInfo = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(currentCameraId, camInfo);

        if (camInfo.facing==(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)) {
            myCamera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);
            myCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            Camera.Parameters params = myCamera.getParameters();
            params.set("cam-mode", 1);
            params.set("cam_mode", 1);
            params.set("camera-id", 1);
            myCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
    }
    return myCamera;


    /*Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
        c.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return c;*/ // returns null if camera is unavailable

}

private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    myCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
    createDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "Scatta");

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/demo/demo1" + "temp" + ".mp4");

    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); 
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);



    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}




private void createDir(String path, String dirName){

    String newFolder = "/" + dirName;
    File myNewFolder = new File(path + newFolder);
    myNewFolder.mkdir();
    mFileTemp = new File(workingPath,newFolder);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
    releaseCamera();    
    myCameraPreview.removeView(myCameraSurfaceView);// release the camera immediately on pause event
}
private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
        mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
        mediaRecorder = null;
        myCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
    }
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if (myCamera != null){
        myCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        myCamera = null;
    }
}

public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
            int height) {

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            return;
        }

        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            //  mCamera.unlock();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("surface changed error"+e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            //  mCamera.unlock();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("IOException"+e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.release();
    }
}


public static Fragment newInstance(Context _context) {
    Recording_Activity f = new Recording_Activity();    
    return f;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
        _xDelta = X- lParams.leftMargin;
        _yDelta = Y- lParams.topMargin;
        System.out.println("_xaDelta value"+_xDelta);
        System.out.println("_yDelta value"+_yDelta);

        if(!recording){
            releaseCamera();
            if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), 
                        "Wait camera is preparing", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),FragmentClass.class));

            }
            else{       
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                    recording = true;
                    btn_record_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_pressed_icon);
                    PreferenceConstants._mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
                    onAnimate(v);
                    countDownTimer.start();
                    iv_progress.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    timer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("camera error"+e.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        File mFile = new File("The output file's absolutePath");
        if(recording){
            try{
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                PreferenceConstants._mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                btn_record_image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),PlaybackScreen.class);
                startActivity(i);
                iv_progress.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            }
            catch(RuntimeException e) {
                mFile.delete();  //you must delete the outputfile when the recorder stop failed.
            } finally {
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                mediaRecorder = null;
            }
            btn_record_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_unpressed_icon);
            recording = false;
            temp++;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            animation.cancel();
        } 
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if(check_value > 0)
        {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            timer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        }
        break;
    }
    layout.invalidate();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Boolean isLoggedin = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
    if(isLoggedin){
        PreferenceConstants._mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
    }
    else{
        PreferenceConstants._mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        iv_cross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
public void onAnimate(View v) {
    animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f);  
    animation.setDuration(8000);  // animation duration 
    iv_progress.startAnimation(animation); 
    animation.setFillAfter(false);

}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        timer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        timer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER );
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),PlaybackScreen.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

}

please help  solve my this issue.i am really getting stuck from this error.

Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904459/android-java-lang-runtimeexception-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service

Comment: @Duggu i saw this link but i didnt get any satisfactory solution

Comment: While you switch your camera from front to rear then just check if the object of ur camera is null or surface view destroys??

Comment: @PiyushGupta hiiii.......i solved tht.....:)......how r u..

Comment: @navya Ok . nice. me fine.

Comment: @PiyushGupta  but i have one issue when i am recording video it is recording in 90" but when showing preview it is inverting

Comment: For that you should check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841122/android-camera-preview-is-sideways , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645960/how-to-set-android-camera-orientation-properly, http://www.androidzeitgeist.com/2012/10/displaying-camera-preview-instant.html

Comment: ok..@PiyushGupta thnku..:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68938/discussion-between-navya-and-piyush-gupta).

Comment: @navya O pagal where are you?

Comment: @navya where are you??

Comment: @PiyushGupta i am here solving issue yr...

Comment: @navya Oh. Thats great!!!

Comment: @PiyushGupta hehehhe...ary yr ...samajh h n aarha mako ...front h le rha h camera bydefault rear k conditin lagane p bhi

Comment: @navya Have you debugged or printed anything in log to check that if is it going to satisfy that condition???

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes it is showing the number of camera and their id..which i am selecting

Comment: @navya Your above posted code is updated code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69125/discussion-between-navya-and-piyush-gupta).