# Android 6.0 RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

An error occurred with my app which ran in Nexus5 (Android6.0).

The error was

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

I had added the permission to the AndroidManifest.xml.

But the app is OK with another phone(Android5.1), and genymotion AVD(Android 4.0).

The key code is below

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"open camera failed",e);
    }

}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33030933/android-6-0-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied?rq=1

Comment: Please add the whole Stacktrace. I guess you got a `SecurityException` as well which is an indicator that you didn't request the camera permission at runtime.

Answer (score 26):

Write in your gradle.build targetSdkVersion 22. It is a temporary solution but work.

Comment: This was also the solution for me. Very weird! What could be the cause?

Comment: It's not weird at all. API levels <=22 don't use run time permission, but 23 do. Check the link in zzzmode's answer.

Comment: Changing Target sdk to 22 is not a solution because it will still fail for android 6 devices, go for proper implementation with android 6 way follow this llink http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Instead of these apply runtime permission for get better result and you can also use this in above 6.0

Answer (score 15):

open Settings -> Apps -> click you app -> Permissions -> open Camera permissions.
you can see:
http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 10):

This happens because, in Android 6.0 the permission model is different. You have to implement the new permission model which asks for the permission on run time. Even if you don't ask it, you can manually enable it in the phone's app setting, but that is not gona work when you publish your app in the play store.
[Here](https://pathofacoder.com/2016/03/19/new-permission-model-in-android/) is an Article on How to get Run time permissions

Also you can check Nick's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions) for getting multiple permissions

Answer (score 6):

From android 6.0 you can handle the app permission weather you will give or not specific permission for an application.
In your case if you didn't enable camera permission for your app then this issues may arise.

So, you need to enable permission from `settings->apps->your_app->enable camera` permission.

Comment: You saved my day ! But, it seem that we have to ask for permissions explicitly as @Amalan Dhananjayan otherwise the final user will not be supposed to know some tricky things as settings->apps->your_app->enable camera

Comment: @Houssem Yes, you need to handle this programmatically. https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en  a good tutorial to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Add Camera Permission before Opening the Camera:

follow the Link for adding Permissions:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html