# QR code Scanner Library with Marshmallow support?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have to use a QR Scanner in my project :

Currently I am using [QRCodeReaderView](https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView) :

But the problem with this library is :

I get

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
>        Exception

In Android 6.0 like explained in this question: [Android 6.0 RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276517/android-6-0-runtimeexception-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service)

As suggested in the answer there I tried to downgrade the target SDK version to 22, It worked fine.

But I could not update my app in Playstore as it denied me to update app with lower target SDK version that previous version.

I also tried to run the demo app of the same **QRCodeReaderView**  and it also crashes in my Marshmallow device. As given [here](http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1891). I also tried to compile the Code in its github on my own but it still crashes.

I tried to look for few other qr code reader but they seem to have put "marshmallow permission " in todo list .

So can you suggest any Library that work with Marshmallow permissions well, or offer help on working with the same library?

Comment: Android Marshmallow requires run time permissions. So try adding run time permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i worked with QrCode one and it is working in all devices well.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

My Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gujrat.quiz.qrcodereader"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Please just have a look at read button and permission only

```
package com.gujrat.quiz.qrcodereader;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.activeandroid.query.Select;
import com.activeandroid.query.Update;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] qrDescription = {"01234", "56789", "02468", "13579"};
    private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        Button read = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read);
        Button show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show);
        Button clear= (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);

        if (getAll().size() == 0) {
            saveInitialDataToDatabase();
        } else {
//            Toast.makeText(this, getAll().size() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                MY_REQUEST_CODE);
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                }

            }
        });

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, ShowReadQrCodeActivity.class));
            }
        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    List<QRDataHelper> scannedProductList = getAlreadyScannedList();
                    for (int i = 0; i < scannedProductList.size(); i++) {
                        updateDatabase(scannedProductList.get(i));
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "List Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "List Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
//             Now user should be able to use camera
                startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            } else {
                // Your app will not have this permission. Turn off all functions
                // that require this permission or it will force close like your
                // original question
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveInitialDataToDatabase() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < qrDescription.length; i++) {
                QRDataHelper qrDataHelper = new QRDataHelper();
                qrDataHelper.setProduct_id(i + "");
                qrDataHelper.setProduct_description(qrDescription[i]);
                qrDataHelper.setProduct_used("0");
                qrDataHelper.save();
            }
        } finally {
//
        }
    }

    public static List<QRDataHelper> getAll() {
        return new Select()
                .from(QRDataHelper.class)
                .where("1")
                .execute();
    }

    public static List<QRDataHelper> getAlreadyScannedList() {
        return new Select()
                .from(QRDataHelper.class)
                .where("product_used = 1")
                .execute();
    }

    public static void updateDatabase(QRDataHelper qrDataHelper) {
        new Update(QRDataHelper.class)
                .set("product_used = 0")
                .where("product_id = ?", qrDataHelper.getProduct_id())
                .execute();
    }


}
```

Activity That calls QrReaderFragment

```
package com.gujrat.quiz.qrcodereader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;
        openFragment(new ScannerFragment());
    }

    public void openFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container,
                fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

And Your QrCodeReader Fragment

```
package com.gujrat.quiz.qrcodereader;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.activeandroid.query.Select;
import com.activeandroid.query.Update;
import com.google.zxing.Result;

import java.util.List;

import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;


public class ScannerFragment extends MasterFragment implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private static final String TAG = ScannerFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mReadText;
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    public ScannerFragment() {
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        return mScannerView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {

        mReadText = rawResult.getText();
        Log.v(TAG, "qrcode rawresult: " + rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
        Log.v(TAG, "qrcode format: " + rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode, pdf417 etc.)



    }

    private void showSuccessDialog() {
        SweetAlertDialog dialog = new SweetAlertDialog(mContext, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("Done!")
                .setContentText("Thank you for using service")
                .setCancelText("Exit!")
                .setConfirmText("Use again!")
                .showCancelButton(true)
                .setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sDialog) {
                        sDialog.dismiss();
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                })
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();
                        resumeScanView();
                    }
                });
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    }

    private void resumeScanView() {
        mReadText = "";
        // Note:
        // * Wait 2 seconds to resume the preview.
        // * On older devices continuously stopping and resuming camera preview can result in freezing the app.
        // * I don't know why this is the case but I don't have the time to figure out.
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(ScannerFragment.this);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    private void startBeepSound() {
        ToneGenerator toneG = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 100);
        toneG.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }




}
```