# Android Studio: Flashlight crashes when turning off

Tags: java, android, crash, flashlight

Im trying to develop a flashlight app as my first "real" app, and almost everything worked. But everytime I want to turn my flashlight off, my app just crashes. Code and Logcat log follows:

```
package com.leuchtstein.flashlight;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public boolean stat = false;
TextView text;
Camera camera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

public void triggerlight(View view) {

    if (stat == false) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();

        text.setText("ON");
        stat = true;


    } else {
        camera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();

        text.setText("OFF");
        stat = false;


    }



}


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.leuchtstein.flashlight.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/desc_textview"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="triggerlight"
        android:text="Turn on/off"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.387" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
https://pastebin.com/tNyF6GvX
```

Thanks in advance, leuchtstein.

EDIT: Yes, I have the uses-permission function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.leuchtstein.flashlight">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following permission in

> AndroidManifest.xml

file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

And follow this thread for more information
[fail-to-connect-to-camera-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904459/android-java-lang-runtimeexception-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service)